# Best Method in Creating User controllers for User and Admin in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

what is the best way to creating a `User controller` for the `User` and `Admin`

In my case I created a namespace for `Admin` which contains the `User` controller, and then for the User I create another Controller in Users namespace. But I sense that my code is `NOT` DRY as Users can Update their details, and Admin can perform the full CRUD. Below is what I did

```
rails generate controller admin/Users index new create show update  delete
rails generate controller Users index show update
```

So the questions is how do I create Uses controller for both Admin and User without repetition of code

PS: I do not want to use any active_admin or any other similar admin gem to do it

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Comment: What's the question here, again? There's no one "best" way.

Comment: +Sergio Tulentsev The question is how am I going to create the User controller for both the Admin and the User that I will not duplicate code

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge: why do you want to not duplicate code here? It seems like incidental duplication to me. user-area and admin-area in a mature app are quite different things, even if they were not in the beginning. Building layers of abstraction here might actually do more harm than good.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so you think it is okay to duplicate code here, even though they are going to be using the same user Model

Answer (score 1):

Is admin a subclass of user? If so, you could do something like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_admin, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy]
  before_action :require_user, only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    # ...
  end

  def show
    # Will fetch either User or Admin based on id
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # ...

  private

  def require_admin
    unless current_user && current_user.is_a?(Admin)
      redirect_to sign_in_url, alert: "You must be an admin."
    end
  end

  def require_user
    unless current_user
      redirect_to sign_in_url, alert: "You must be signed in."
    end
  end
end
```

Otherwise, if they are two distinct classes and tables, I think it would be appropriate to have separate controllers to manage them.

**Updating based on comments**

If you have the same functionality for some actions and different for others, you *could* do some inheritance.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    # same for both
  end

  def update
    # same for both
  end
end
```

and then subclass them

```
class User::UsersController < ::UsersController
  def show
    # different
  end
end

class Admin::UsersController < ::UsersController
  def show
    # different
  end

  def create
    # admin-only
  end
end
```

I really think that's a bit convoluted and confusing, but you can see if it will work for you.

Personally, I would make a global `UsersController` that the admin and user **both** use to update **their own** users. Then have a separate `Admin::UsersController` that **admins** use to CRUD **any** user.

Comment: yeah, User and Admin belong to the same model User, but their controller would do different things, so the #Show of the 'User' will be different from the #Show of the 'Admin'

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge I've updated the answer. I would have separate controllers in that case. One UsersController and one Admin::UsersController. The first admins/users can use to update their own account. The second admins can use to update any account.

Comment: yeah the second one makes sense to me, let me try that implementation, thanks